# how to replace substring with particular value dynamically?

Tags: java

I have values in my properties file like,

> bloodpressure.properties :
>       (key,value) : (bloodpressure,your blood pressure was ***B6***, this is high)

In My java class, i am reading values from properties file but i want to replace values with calculated values like,

```
String B6 = "120";
Properties bp = new Properties();
bp.load(new FileInputStream("filename"));

String bpstr = bp.getProperty(bloodpressure);
```

now, i want to replace B6 value with above B6 value(120).
How can i do it dynamically?, i have lot of string like this.

I just want to iterate through properties file, the values should replace with calculated values.

Comment: Have you tried: `String bpstr = bp.getProperty(bloodpressure).replace("B6", B6);`?

Comment: I am iterating through properties file, it has 150 pairs like this.I couldn't replace it while iterating. While displaying string only it should take value from class string . I am thinking, is there separate way of representing properties file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MessageFormat.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) does that:

```
String msg = "Your blood pressure is {0}";
System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(msg, 120));
```

Basically, you define placeholders and replace them with your values. This is especially helpful for internationalization, where the order of appearance of the placeholders may change in different languages.

Answer (score 0):

use String.replace()

```
bpstr.replace("B6",B6);
```

UPDATE

or if you have multible B6 instances you can use the replaceAll

```
bpstr.replaceAll("B6",B6);
```

Comment: I am iterating through properties file, it has 150 pairs like this.I couldn't replace it while iterating. While displaying string only it should take value from class string . I am thinking, is there separate way of representing properties file?

Comment: You are replacing String "B6", by itself "B6"!

Comment: He is replacing it with B6 variable value. Check the sample code in the question.

Comment: MaVRoSCy I didn't downvote. I was telling @cl-r that your code was doing the replacement with the variable specified in the question.

Comment: and that's what is asked by the user. Isn't it?

Comment: As far as I know, it is. I think your code is doing the right thing here :)

Comment: Agreed, this is a valid (and at the moment IMO the best answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
      MessageFormat.format does that:

      String msg = "Your blood pressure is {0}";
      System.out.println(MessageFormat.format(msg, 120));
```

This will do the thing what you want. Here, {0} is replaced by 120.